# How to rotate a bitmap when drawing a subset of it?

Tags: android, bitmap, rotation, drawbitmap

I am using

```
pCanvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, mRectSrc, mRectDst, mPainter);
```

to draw a subset of a bitmap. I wondering how I can rotate that bitmap
without affecting the view. In my attempts, when I set the canvas to rotate
the whole view (viewport) is rotated. This is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when I had to draw rotated text, I found the procedure is to call `Canvas.save()`, rotate (remembering that the center point remains the same), do the drawing and then call `Canvas.restore()`. I suppose it's just the same in this case.

Comment: Actually, I don't have to use save/restore.

Comment: @user445299 well that's if you have to draw a bitmap and *then* rotate the whole canvas. If you need to do some "normal" drawing and then draw a rotated bitmap, you first have to save, rotate the canvas, draw as if it were "normal" and then restore.

Answer (score 0):

Only way I know of is to use a Matrix.  Try this pseudocode:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.your_bitmap);
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(90);
Bitmap rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

Comment: Here's what's working for me (minus the skewed rectangles):

1. Convert int src and dst Rects to s, r RectFs (float) 
2. Matrix m = new Matrix();
3. m.postRotate(...);
4. m.mapRect(r, s)
5. Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap, 0, 0, w, h, m, true);
6...//other steps
7. canvas.drawBitmap(rotatedBitmap, SrcRect, r, painter);